# Populating select box with neighborhoods of the selected city using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm all afternoon trying to run my code, but I'm doing something wrong. I will explain what I need to do.
I need to make when the user selects his city in a select box the neighborhoods corresponding to that city needs to be inserted into another select box. For this, I am using the following logic:
I have two tables in my database, one called *cities* and other called *neighborhoods*. The struct of the table *cities* is:
**city_id (PRIMARY_KEY)**
**city_name**
The struct of the table *neighborhoods* is:
**neighborhood_id (PRIMARY_KEY)**
**city_id** (To know what city the neighborhood belongs.)
**neighborhood_name**
Now in the register page I have this code to populate the **user_city_id** select box:

```
<label>City <span style='color: red'>*</span><br/>
<select id='user_city_id' name='user_city_id'>
<option value=''>-- Select a city --</option>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cities ORDER BY city_id";

    foreach($connection->query($sql) as $city)
    {
        echo "<option value='{$city['city_id']}'>{$city['city_name']}</option>";
    }
?>
</select></label>
```

Ok, this code part insert the cities in select box with their ID in values and names. All right here.
Below I have the neighborhood select box with:

```
<label>Neighborhood <span style='color: red'>*</span><br/>
<select id='user_neighborhood_id' name='user_neighborhood_id'>
    <option value=''>-- Select a neighborhood --</option>
</select></label>
```

Now is the hard part, the AJAX. I'm trying using jQuery and JSON to parse the data with the following code:

```
$(function(){
$('#user_city_id').change(function()
{
    if($(this).val())
    {
        $.getJSON('neighborhood.ajax.php?search=', {city_id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j)
        {
            var options = '<option value=""></option>'; 
            for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++)
            {
                options += '<option value="' + j[i].neighborhood_id + '">' + j[i].neighborhood_name + '</option>';
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $('#user_neighborhood_id').html('<option value="">-- Select a neighborhood --</option>');
    }
});});
```

The file to process the data is **neighborhood.ajax.php**. In this file I have:

```
require_once("db-connect.php");

$city_id = $_GET['user_city_id'];

$neighborhoods = array();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM neighborhoods WHERE city_id = {$city_id} ORDER BY neighborhood_name";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    extract($row);
    $neighborhoods[] = array
    (
        'neighborhood_id'   => $neighborhood_id,
        'neighborhood_name' => $neighborhood_name
    );
}

echo(json_encode($neighborhoods));
```

...but simply nothing happens! Of course I'm doing something wrong, but so far I could not solve by myself. I'm trying and nothing. 
I had never worked with AJAX. What is missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution today by myself. 
It was a terribly simple solution that I could not see yesterday due to fatigue. I just noticed that I did not send the statement to insert HTML in select box, the `options` var data. I just inserted it with `$('#user_neighborhood_id').html(options).show();`. Here are the solution:

```
$(function(){
$('#user_city_id').change(function()
{
    if($(this).val())
    {
        $.getJSON('neighborhood.ajax.php?search=', {city_id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j)
        {
            var options = '<option value=""></option>'; 
            for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++)
            {
                options += '<option value="' + j[i].neighborhood_id + '">' + j[i].neighborhood_name + '</option>';
            }
            $('#user_neighborhood_id').html(options).show();
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $('#user_neighborhood_id').html('<option value="">-- Select a neighborhood --</option>');
    }
});});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the browser that the data being sent from the server is JSON.

Add this line at the top of **neighborhood.ajax.php**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: Use the Net tab of your browser's developer tools to see the traffic to and from the server.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor

Comment: What I could tell was that the value of CITY_ID variable is passed when I select, but still have no answer. I think my PHP script is with deformities.